# Near blockchain assign payment at backend

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm new to backend and near blockchain
https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/NCD.L1.sample--lottery
NCD.L1.sample--lottery
When Run the 2nd times

```
./scripts/2.play.sh
```

2nd play need to pay $1 near. How to run the 2nd play with set the payment.
Any help, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the amount of NEAR tokens as a number after the play command and it will be passed to the variable called `$1` in the script

So you will write this:

```
./scripts/2.play.sh 5
```

and this will send 5 NEAR tokens `$PLAYER` account to the contract

You can read the code of the script here:
https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/NCD.L1.sample--lottery/blob/main/scripts/2.play.sh

Comment: Is rainbow here.